# Getting the closest element using javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function toDelete(book_id){
 var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
 $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'url-to-delete-book',
  data:{ book_id: book_id },
  success: function(response){
   if(response == 'success'){
    parent.slideUp(200,function() {
     parent.remove();
    });
   }
  }
 })
};
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>No</th>
   <th>Title</th>
   <th>Author</th>
   <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Harry Potter</td>
   <td>J.K Rowling</td>
   <td><a href="javascript:;" onclick="toDelete(2)">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>The Great Gatsby</td>
   <td>F. Scott Fitzgerald</td>
   <td><a href="javascript:;" onclick="toDelete(1)">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to delete the row of the table when the book data is deleted. But when I do the `$(this).closest('tr')` in the javascript function, I'm having this in the console `e.fn.init [prevObject: e.fn.init(1), contect: undefined]`. How do I get the parent element inside the function? Thank you.

Comment: It Would be better if you assigned dynamic id's to the rows.

Comment: Try this instead: `this.parentNode.parentNode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var parent = $(this).closest('tr');`

You're passing `this` to jQuery, but do you know what `this` is, in this context? If the function is "just" called, like in this case, `this` will be the function that is called (`function toDelete`) - you can log it in your console by issuing `console.log(this)`. And that function has no closest `<tr>` element.

You should either call the function with the element to select the closest `<tr>` from as `this` argument (e.g. `toDelete.call(this, 1)` from inside the onclick), or pass the element as an argument to the `toDelete` function (e.g. `toDelete(this, 1)`, while the function definition is `function toDelete(element, book_id)` and the jQuery selector would be `$(element).closest('tr')`.

---

*Minor update*

Apparently I was not fully aware of what `this` means in this context. I tried in Chrome's developer console, and `this` seems to be not the event (as CBroe mentions), nor the function (as I mentioned), but the `Window` object.

```
function a() { console.log(this); }
function x() { console.log(this); }
x.prototype.y = function() { console.log(this); }

a(); // Window
x(); // Window
x.y(); // x
```

Comment: Thank you. It helps me a lot.

Comment: `this` is the actual _event_ object in this instance; that is due to the fact that “old-school” event handling via HTML attributes was used. The _proper_ solution to this would be to do event handling via the appropriate jQuery mechanisms to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```js
function toDelete(book_id){
 var parent = $(event.target).closest("tr");

 $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'url-to-delete-book',
  data:{ book_id: book_id },
  success: function(response){
   if(response == 'success'){
    parent.slideUp(200,function() {
     parent.remove();
    });
   }
  }
 });
   };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>No</th>
   <th>Title</th>
   <th>Author</th>
   <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Harry Potter</td>
   <td>J.K Rowling</td>
   <td><a href="javascript:;" onclick="toDelete(2)">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>The Great Gatsby</td>
   <td>F. Scott Fitzgerald</td>
   <td><a href="javascript:;" onclick="toDelete(1)">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```